# Как работает данный код на php?

Tags: php, exif

Не могу понять, для чего это выполняется и как это работает?

```
 $lat = 1;
    $long = 1;
    if ($exif[“GPSLatitudeRef”] == ‘N’) {
        $lat = -1;
    }
    if ($exif[“GPSLongitudeRef”] == ‘E’) {
        $long = -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, вычисляет знак, который имеют географические координаты, т. е. если это северная широта (`N`) или восточная долгота (`E`), координата становится отрицательной.

Answer (score 3):

GPSLatitudeRef и GPSLongitudeRef - это GPS теги и часть стандарта EXIF: https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/GPS.html

соответственно, изначально переменные $lat и $long устанавливаются в 1 (обозначение южной широты и западной долготы внутри программы). Далее проверяется, если соответствующие значения EXIF соответствуют северной широте или восточной долготе, то соответствующие переменные меняют значение на -1 (видимо, внутреннее обозначение в программе)